# Assign min and max values to WKInterfaceSlider in code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit

I want to assign the minimum and maximum value for`WKInterfaceSlider` ( **WatchKit** ) in the Swift code, not through the interface because I will get new values ( prices ) from the server.

which won't always be the same. In my current code I receive an error when i use this command with the Double value, highestBid

```
WKInterfaceSlider.setValue(highestBid)
```

Error:

> Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(Double)'.

```
import Foundation
import WatchKit
import UIKit

class slideViewController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet weak var lblPrice: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var slider: WKInterfaceSlider!
@IBOutlet weak var bidBtn: WKInterfaceButton!


@IBAction func sliderButton(value: Float) {

    var kavelPrice:Double = 6000
    var bidAmounts:Double = (kavelPrice / 100 * 2)
    var midPrice:Double = (bidAmounts * 5 )
    var highestBid:Double = (midPrice + kavelPrice)
    var lowestBid:Double = kavelPrice

    slider.setValue()

    let roundedValue = Int(round(value))
    self.lblPrice.setText("\(roundedValue)")
}

 @IBAction func bidPrice() {

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the a minimum or maximum value for a `WKInterfaceSlider` in code. These values can only be set in interface builder. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceSlider_class/) for more details.